# USing JSON array for Morris line chart

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

The PHP function sends an array, which looks like this:

```
[{"day":1,"amount":54296.5},{"day":2,"amount":869}]
```

When I loop it through a variable using each:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val){
  ty.push({'index': key, 'Value' : val}); 
});
```

The result is:

```
0:Object
1:Object
length:2
```

Which seems surely wrong.

What's the proper way to  store the array and use it for the chart?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I want to store the response array  in a local variable using JS and use it for Morrischart

Comment: Yes your loop is correct.

Answer (score 0):

so in php use jsonEncoder for your data 
after you just write the name of variable something like

mystuff = [{"day":1,"amount":54296.5},{"day":2,"amount":869}]

mystuff["day"].text

Answer (score 0):

Here you with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/5peg2aqt/

```js
var data = [{"day":1,"amount":54296.5},{"day":2,"amount":869}];

var ty = [];

$.each(data, function(key, val){
  ty.push({'index': data[key]["day"], 'Value' : data[key]["amount"]}); 
});

console.log(ty);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the Morris Line Chart with your non-manipulated data from php https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjQgqm